# Are "on" and "about" absolute synonyms?

Tags: meaning

Are these two sentences synonymous?

> I need your advice on this issue.
>
> I need your advice about this issue.

Do they exactly mean the same thing? Or are there slight nuances between the two words? I always thought they were absolute synonyms unless they were used as part of a phrasal verb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the phrase you give, "on" and "about" are exact synonyms to my ears (USA).

Of course in other contexts, "about" and "on" are often very different. e.g. "sitting on the table", "laughing about a joke", etc.